# interactive cpu governor?

Tags: cpu

my processor is a Core2Duo 2.16 GHz (macbook 4.1)
but cpufreq only shows four Governors:
conservative
ondemand
powersave
performance

no shows interactive and userspace

the governor that I've always liked is interactive, inclusive is the one I use in my google nexus one, I've always been successful

is there any way to activate or select interactive as governor in ubuntu 11.04?

Greetings and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `interactive` governor is [made by/for Cyanogenmod](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/cm-kernel/commit/255f13bf41f368aa51638a854ed69cfc60f39120), so it's not in the mainline and hence not in the Ubuntu kernel.

It will land in Ubuntu if it's merged into the mainline kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The interactive governor is [included in the Android](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-4.9/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_interactive.c) and [the Chrome OS](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/kernel-next/+/chromeos-cpufreq_interactive-3.10/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq_interactive.c) mainline kernels but not in the Linux one. Ubuntu does not include the `interactive` governor because that.

There was many attempts to introduce the `interactive` governor into the linux mainline. There was a [patch RFC](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=132867057910479&w=2) in 2012, a [patch-set for Linux](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1510.3/01959.html) in 2015 and a [patchset](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9128637/) in 2016. Linaro [worked on that subject too](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/linux-linaro/+spec/cpufreq-latency-improvements) to increase the [cooperation of cpufreq with the scheduler](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/linux-linaro/+spec/cpufreq-latency-improvements). However, there were many concerns on using cpu-specific information and, I think, linux maintainers preferred to improve the governors that already existed. There is a recent [`schedutil` governor](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/cpufreq_and_scheduler_0.pdf), [introduced in 2016](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-47-schedutil&num=1) (Linux 4.7), that estimates CPU utilization using the per-entity load tracking.

If you are interested, there are some [kernel packages](https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/kernel) for running Ubuntu on Microsoft Surface Pro that includes the `interactive` governor. They use the [RobMcCathie kernel patches](https://github.com/korrode/kernel-patches) used for a [Manjaro-based kernel](http://paradoxcomputers.com.au/manjaro/packages/desktop-kernel-test/).